# RDS Login for additional RDS-Host not possible

Tags: rds, session, host

Following Situation:

Server 2012 R2 (Name: TS)
- RDS Gateway, Broker, Host
- In LAN
- Self created certificate "rds.example.com"

Server 2012 R2 (Name: TS1)
- RDS Host
- In LAN
- Self created certificate "rds.example.com" (Change by Power Shell to use this certificate)

Server 2012 R2 (Name: Lic)
- RDS License Server
- In LAN

Firewall:
- NAT for TCP 3389 to "TS"

From the internal Network I'm able to connect to any Host without any Problem. And yes `Do not use Gateway for internal Connections` is already unchecked, so it should use the Gateway.

From external I can only Login to the RDS-Host which is installed on the Gateway/Broker Server.

The error message I get is:

> Cannot connect to Remote Desktop Server, please check if Remote
>   Desktop is activated

Unfortunately I cannot find any error message in the logs, which will Point me towards a direction.
I only see the Gateway is delegating to TS1 and the Authentication is successful.

*I have the same Situation for RemoteApp over HTTPS, but this is working fine.
Only difference: The Host-Server(TS1) is using a self-signed certificate. I also tried a self-signed certificate for the current Situation, but didn`t work.*

Answer (score 0):

> From external I can only Login to the RDS-Host which is installed on the Gateway/Broker Server.
>
> The error message I get is:
>
> Cannot connect to Remote Desktop Server, please check if Remote Desktop is activated

Do you mean you cant connect externally using the RD Gateway?

If so, did you expose and forward port 443 to the gateway server? Based on your question it looks like you forwarded 3389, but RD Gateway uses 443.

You should close 3389 and open 443 to "TS".

Comment: I can connect to the RD Gateway.
I can also work on the RD Host which is installed on the RD Gateway.
But I cannot connect if the RD Gateway forwards my request (by load balancing) to a second RD Host, which is a separate Server.
This is where I get the error message.